# Django get all foreign key names of a model

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I need to get all foreign key names of a single model. For example if a model name is `UserProfile` and it has `user`, `customer`, and `comment` as foreign keys means by single code I want to get all foreign key names of the `UserProfile` model.

Comment: @Zeeker I tried [k.name for k in obj._meta._field_name_cache if 'foreign_related_fields' in dir(k)]

Comment: @Zeeker I tried this too [k.name for k in obj._meta._field_name_cache if k.__class__.__name__ == "ForeignKey"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find relations like so: `UserProfile._meta.get_all_related_objects()`

You can iterate through fields on the model directly via `UserProfile._meta.fields`

You can determine the field type via `field.get_internal_type()`

```
for field in UserProfile._meta.fields:
    if field.get_internal_type() == 'ForeignKey':
        print 'found a foreign key'
```

Comment: `get_all_related_objects` has been deprecated and is no longer present starting with Django 1.10 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api

Comment: You can store the fields with this 1 liner `fields = [field for field in YourModel._meta.fields if field.get_internal_type() == 'ForeignKey']`

Comment: @radtek nice one liner. One liners are not always the most communicative/easy to read, so I tend to avoid them. It's not wrong, but it's not right either.